# How to access a network shared drive inside Invoke-command

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I was using below script to copy files from network share to local drive. But,I was not able to access path and getting Path not found error. MY use case is I need to execute this script from Jenkins server and remote into server1 and then have copy files from shared directory (\server2\QlikView) which is already mounted to the server1 as S:\ drive. I was able to access this shared path from powershell If I run the command from server1.But, not inside Invoke-Command script block as shown. Any thoughts on this?

```
$server = "server1"
$source_dir = "\\server2\QlikView"
$processing_dir = "M:\script_test\processing"
$processed_dir = ""
$user = 'Domain\user1'
$Password = '******'
$SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $SecurePassword

 Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
  param ($server,$source_dir,$processing_dir)
echo "$source_dir"
 Test-path $source_dir
 copy-item -Path $source_dir\* -Destination M:\script_test
  } -ArgumentList $server,$source_dir,$processing_dir
```

Comment: Why do you think that a mapped network drive (`M` in particular) is mapped the same way (e.g. root _UNC path_) on a remote computer?

Answer (score 1):

By default PowerShell remoting does not allow credential delegation or "second hop". If you want to connect to a remote machine (in this case a network share) from a remoting session, you need to allow the credentials to be delegated to that machine. To allow it you need to configure CredSSP. Take a look here for details on the problems as well as how to set it up: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/11/14/enable-powershell-second-hop-functionality-with-credssp/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I resolved this issue by using Net Use /user:$user //server1/dir1 $Password.

Comment: "CredSSP is only available on Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/cc540483(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: @workholic how did use Net Use with your example?
I have the same issue and I am completely stuck

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a scheduled task.  The system user can access active directory shares.

```
icm comp001 { 
  $action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'cmd' -argument '/c \\sccmserver\sources\applications\install.bat > c:\users\admin\install.log 2>&1'
  Register-ScheduledTask -action $action -taskname install -user system -force > $null
  Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName install
  while ((Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName install).State -ne 'Ready') {
    Write-Verbose -Message 'Waiting on scheduled task...' }
  Get-ScheduledTask install | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo | select LastTaskResult
}
```